# Calculate the coordinates of the point P, knowing that A=(2,0) and OA=AB.

Tags: geometry, triangles

[image]

I have the following problem. In the figure, the circumference is tangent to the Y-axis in the point *P*, the point *A* has coordinates (2,0) and *OA=AB*. I am asked to calculate the coordinates of the point *P*.

This is what I thought: I want to calculate the center of the circumference, given that I know the coordinates of two points in it. If I call this center *C*, then, for example, *AC=PC*, and knowing what the distance between two points is, I'd be able to find the coordinates of the point P.
However, I am not being able to find the coordinates of the center.

I am supposed to be able to solve this with a not so advanced math. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see what's random here or exactly what you mean by $OA=OB$.

Comment: Oh, sorry. *O* is the origin of the plane (where there is what looks like a *C*). And I wanted to calculate the center knowing the coordinates of the points A and B.

Comment: Three points define a circle; see here for various ways of finding the center and radius: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/213658/get-the-equation-of-a-circle-when-given-3-points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The center of the circle is $(3, b)$. $3$ came from mid point between A and B, and it's also the radius of the circle.
And
$$b^2=r^2-1^2=3^2-1=8$$
So $P=(0,2\sqrt2)$.

Comment: I'm sorry, why does $b^2=r^2-1^2$?

Comment: Oh, I get it now.