# Furmula to get a centre of circle that connects points $A(3;0)$, $B(4;5)$, $C(0;3)$. Equation for circle that connects same points.

Tags: geometry, circles

In Math Olympiad, I needed to create an equation for circle that connects points $A(3;0)$, $B(5;4)$, $C(0;3)$.

I did it in this way:

1) draw segments connecting those points - $AB, BC, CA$

2) draw perpendiculars from the centre of the segments

3) the point where all perpendiculars meet is the centre of circle that connects points $A(3;0)$, $B(5;4)$, $C(0;3)$

4) calculated the Radius of the circle ($R = 2.69$) and created equation: 
\begin{align*} 
(x−a)^2 + (y−b)^2 & = r^2\\
(x−2.67)^2 + (y−2.67)^2 & = 7.22
\end{align*}

[img]https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlA96.png

*But I am wondering if either is possible:*

1) to solve it in easier/faster way

2) to create ***formula to get a centre of circle that connects points $A(3;0)$, $B(4;5)$, $C(0;3)$.***

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/213658/265466) for several methods. Additionally, you know from points $A$ and $C$ that the center must lie somewhere on the line $x=y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can plug in the coordinates of Points in the General circle equation:
$$(x-x_M)^2+(y-y_M)^2=R^2$$
this gives
$$(3-x_M)^2+y_M^2=R^2$$
$$(4-x_M)^2+(5-y_M)^2=R^2$$
$$x_M^2+(3-y_M)^2=R^2$$
and solve this for $$x_M,y_M,R$$