# How to shift a function of a half circle on the x-axis?

Tags: functions, circles

I want to have a half circle function from $x=0$ to $x=0.056$
with $f(0)=0$ and $f(0.056)=0$, and the highest point at $f(0.056/2) = 0.001$

I tried: 
$$
f(x) = \sqrt{0.001^2 - ( ( [0.001\times0.056]-x ) / 0.056)^2 }
$$
but it will give me an error, because the number in the sqrt gets negative.

Comment: $f(x)=0.001\sqrt{1-\dfrac{(x-0.028)^2}{0.028^2}}$ is a half ellipse with the desired points

Comment: @J.W.Tanner No, that equation does not work. It gives me complex values. :(

Comment: If $0\le x\le 0.056$, then $-0.028\le x-0.028\le 0.028$, so $(x-0.028)^2\le0.028^2$, so $\dfrac{(x-0.028)^2}{0.028^2}\le1$ so $1-\dfrac{(x-0.028)^2}{0.028^2}\ge0$ so $f(x)$ is real

Comment: @J.W.Tanner : OP is looking for a circle. Its center is not on the x-axis because the height is not equal to half the distance between x-intercepts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the equation of a circle when given 3 points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/213658/get-the-equation-of-a-circle-when-given-3-points)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I put f(x) = 0.001*sqrt(1 - (x-0.028)^2 / (0.028)^2 ) in wolframAlpha or in Matlab and it says, that there are complex values...

Comment: @thale00:  Try [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+f%28x%29+%3D+0.001*sqrt%281+-+%28x-0.028%29%5E2+%2F+%280.028%29%5E2+%29+for+x%3D0+to+0.056)

Comment: @MPW:  now I see what you're saying

Comment: I was confused because OP wanted "a function from $x=0$ to $x=0.056$"

Comment: @J.W.Tanner : I understand, I was thinking along the same lines and nearly posted a wrong answer. Then I noticed the height was wrong. Since a circle was specified, I realized the two endpoints do not lie in a diameter.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Suppose the center is at $(a,b)$ and the radius is $r$, so that the equation of the circle is of the form $$(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 = r^2.$$
Since you know three points on the circle, you can write a system of three equations in three unknowns. Solve that system for the unknown parameters $a$, $b$, and $r$. Your function will be
$$f(x)=b + \sqrt{r^2 - (x-a)^2}$$
This function has domain $[a-r, a+r]$, the projection of the horizontal diameter onto the $x$-axis.